# Warning: some journal files were not opened due to insufficient permissions

Tags: linux, systemd, services, systemctl

I receive this warning when running `systemctl status <servicename>.service` after manually stopping my newly installed servce.

"Warning: some journal files were not opened due to insufficient permissions."

What does it mean and what does it refer to by journal files ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

tl;dr:  Use `sudo systemctl status ...`.

When you use `systemctl`, you are using an agent to talk to `systemd` which is a root process.  `systemd` may talk back to you, but it isn't going to tell you the whole story unless you have permissions to do so.

Part of `systemctl status` is showing you the latest journal entries for that unit.

Files in `/var/log/journal/{machine-id}/*.journal` have the following permissions on my setup:

```
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 117440512 Jun 28 08:02 system@0005e27bc7072026-42898ef22d6040a1.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal  92274688 May 31 08:21 system@70d66b763a2e48928c16fc2c8a23fbfa-0000000000000001-0005e0363468a504.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal  50331648 Jun  2 12:05 system@70d66b763a2e48928c16fc2c8a23fbfa-000000000001a077-0005e048c99c4a31.journal
```

This means `root` and members of `systemd-journal` can read the journal-files directly.  The `+` indicates that additional permissions (ACLs) are also set:

```
$ getfacl system@70d66b76...a504.journal
...
group:adm:r-x     #effective:r--
...
```

This says that anyone in group `adm` also has read-permissions.

`systemd` takes this into account when you ask it to tell you about the journal.  If you aren't in grounp `systemd-journal` or `adm`, then `systemd` will check things like whether the journal belongs to your `--user` bus, or if there are specific `polkit` rules that grant you permission to specific entries.  It will tell you only what you're allowed to know.

The simplest answer is to use `sudo systemctl status` to effectively become `root` and then ask `systemctl` for that info.

Comment: And members of `adm` can also view all journal messages.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Quolonel Question in the above comment, the preferable (and certainly easiest) way might be to make sure your user belongs to the `adm` group.  On my Ubuntu system this can be achieved thus:

```bash
sudo usermod -G adm <myuser>
```

Log out your user session and log back in and you should be able to access that information without the need to `sudo`.